# Number of sets that contain at least one arithmetic progression

Tags: combinatorics, limits, arithmetic-progressions

Let $f(n)$ denotes number of subsets of set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ that contain at least one arithmetic progression of length $3$.

I made some calculation in c++ and there are some first values:
$$f(3)=1,f(4)=3,f(5)=9, f(6)= 24, f(7)=63, f(8)=150, f(9)=343, f(10)=746$$
...
The thing i saw is that sequence $a_{n}=\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$ is bounded by $2$ and $3$, and it is at some point strictly decreasing.

> Is this true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n}=2$?

If so, then how to calculate $f(n)$?

> How to find an upper bound of $f(n)$?

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A018788](https://oeis.org/A018788). The entry contains almost no information. The complementary entry [A051013](https://oeis.org/A051013) has a link to [this MathWorld page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonaveragingSequence.html) that contains an interesting result for infinite sequences, but I don't think it's directly relevant to your question.